# Sql statement to join two table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Suppose I have two table

Table Name group

column 1: giver

column 2: acceptor

Table name userinfo

column 1: name

column 2: status

i want to select giver,acceptor and userinfo.status  that from group table where giver or acceptor whose name is zakir that giver or acceptor exist in uerinfo table as name.

Need Help to write sql statement for taht query..
Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: where is the joining key ?

Comment: What have you tried?  And is there any relationship between those 2 tables?

Comment: Yes sir I edited my post you may see .. :)
yes sir userinfo tables name and groups table acceptor or giver are same.

For example if userinfo table name is zakir then groups table acceptor or giver could also be zakir

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is also known as the [INNER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) clause in an SQL Statement.

Depending on the relationship you can create an INNER JOIN to potentially connect the two variables that are identical.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Extracted from [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query,

```
SELECT 
gp.giver,gp.acceptor,ui.status 
FROM group as gp JOIN userinfo as ui 
on ui.name = 'zakir' 
AND (gp.giver = 'zakir' or gp.acceptor = 'zakir')
```

Or try this without join,

```
SELECT 
gp.giver,gp.acceptor,ui.status 
FROM group as gp, userinfo as ui 
WHERE ui.name = 'zakir' 
AND (gp.giver = 'zakir' or gp.acceptor = 'zakir')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT `group`.`giver`, `group`.`acceptor`, `userinfo`.`status`
FROM `group`, `userinfo`
WHERE (`group`.`giver` = 'zakir' OR `group`.`acceptor` = 'zakir')
  AND `userinfo`.`name` = 'zakir'
```

Comment: Guys.. Please don post the same answer again and again. Please check the previous answers and then post your own answers.

Comment: @HarishChinju And how do you see my answer as similar to yours? I escaped the tables and columns names because some of them are reserved keywords. You did not. Plus you're answer was less than 1 second earlier than mine, how would I be able to check it before posting? Are we in a race here or something?

Comment: Between our answers only difference is I have used alias name, where you haven't used and you have done it escaped sequence to avoid reserved keyword conflict. thats a great job. But my suggestion is, I think there would be a msg before we post. So before posting we can just have a refresh to check is there any answer posted. Anyway lets see whether this solves his problem.????? Right.?

Answer (score 1):

```
select g.giver, g.acceptor u.status
from group g, userinfo u
where u.name = 'zakir'
and (g.giver = u.name or g.acceptor = u.name)
```

It should do a part of the job.

Comment: Guys.. Please don post the same answer again and again. Please check the previous answers and then post your own answers.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you want the status for both the giver and the acceptor

May need a little tweaking for mysql syntax

```
Select giver, g.status, acceptor, a.status 
FROM GROUP 
join userinfo as g on group.giver = g.name
join userinfo as a on group.acceptor = a.name
where (giver = 'zakir' or acceptor = 'zakir')
```